# Display the url of the first image of the jquery page

Tags: jquery

I want to print on page instead of alert

```
<div id="menu">
  <img class="thm" src="images/test1.png" />
  <img class="thm" src="images/test2.png" />
  <img class="thm" src="images/test3.png" />
</div>
<div id="content">
  <img id="main" />
</div>

<script>
  var img = document.getElementById('i');

  alert(img.getAttribute('src')); // foo.jpg
  alert(img.src); // http://..../foo.jpg
</script>
```

I want to print on page instead of alert and Display url of first image of page

Comment: yes  jquery solution

Comment: this not working

Comment: ok its true please Look up again ... I want Display url of first image of page .... I deleted id.

Comment: $("#src").text($("img:first-of-type").attr("src"));
   document.write(img.src); this not work  I want it printed like this here

Comment: I want it to be jQuery for use in schema .... schema does not display div

Comment: you say what is output in jQuery, I don't know. schema is a jQuery ... <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",